# npm link dev packages when using docker dev containers

Tags: docker, npm-link, vscode-devcontainer

Use `npm link` for authoring multiple packages simultaneously in docker dev containers

PkgA is a dependency of PkgB, I'm making changes to both. Goal is to be able to link PkgA in PkgB without publishing each small update and re-installing. npm|yarn link solve this, but I'm developing in docker containers.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14325

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 1. Create a directory on the host machine to serve as the global repo

(I like to make a docker dir and put all of my volumes in it)

```
mkdir -p ~/docker/volumes/yalc
```

## 2. Mount the volume in both (or more) dev containers

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced

```
devcontainer.json

...
"mounts": ["source=/Users/evan/docker/volumes/yalc,target=/yalc,type=bind,consistency=cached"],
...
```

and rebuild the container

## 3. Install yalc and publish the package (In dependency repo container)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc

```
npm i yalc -g
yalc publish --store-folder /yalc
```

**--store-folder** tells yalc to publish the repo to our volume

## 4. Link to the package in consuming repo

consider adding yalc to `.gitignore` first:

```
.yalc
yalc.lock
```

Run the link command

```
npm i yalc -g
yalc link PkgA --store-folder /yalc
```

Where `PkgA` is the name of the package as defined in it's `package.json`